# VLAN in same Subnet possible?

Tags: subnet, vlan

SO this is more of a confirmation I am looking for than a real question.

My setup is as follows:

Router > managed switch > other devices.

in the category other devices I have a pc with two 1gbps nics and many other devices.

In the managed switch: VLAN ALL = Port1, VLAN 1 = Port2, VLAN 2 = Remaining ports

PC with 2 nics: NIC1=connected with Port2 managed switch NIC2=connected with Port3 managed switch

ROUTER: Connected with Port1 of managed switch

I tested this config useing a laptop and the laptop got a ip adress and I had internet but could not find any other devices in the network eventough they are in the same subnet. No problem this is what i want. But when it was plugged in a port which was in vlan2 it found all devices directly

**What am i trying to achieve?**

I want to use NIC1 of the pc for all LAN traffic by pulling all streams from all local devices over this NIC1. Then I want to use NIC2 for all other traffic and mainly wan traffic.

Is it possible with the configuration above? and is correct to have both VLAN1 and VLAN2 on the same subnet?

And last question, I was scared of it but it did not seem to happen. Because Port1 of the managed switch has VLAN: ALL I thought maybe all traffic then will go through that port and devices will be able to find eathother by communicating over the router but that also did not seem to happen? Or is that normal? or the reason is the following:

My internet provider sends internet over VLAN:34 and IPTV over VLAN:4....Could the router be in VLAN:34 which is the reason why there is no communication between VLAN1 and VLAN2 as the router as a middleware...

And everywhere, on forums and guides is is given that a vlan has it's own subnet or needs it but I did some tests successfully within the same subnet.Is this true?

But both VLAN1 and VLAN2 are in the same subnet 192.168.2.0/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routers route between networks, not from a network to the same network, and you need a router to send traffic from one VLAN (layer-2 domain) to another.

If your PC has two interfaces addressed in the same layer-3 network, it will choose one to use for all traffic destined to that network; it will have no way to know which interface to use for which addresses. Routing must be deterministic.

The way to do what you want is to have different networks on the different VLANs. The interfaces between the router and the switch will need to be configured as a trunk, and the router will need a virtual interface for each network on the trunk. The router will also need to be configured to NAT to the public Internet for all the VLAN networks.

Comment: Hi ron. You mean to say that eventough one networkinterface is in the same vlan as the rest and the other is not the pc wont be able to communicate with the other devices? I tought it will just try with both until one gets a resonse back? So it is a must for vlans to have their own subnet?

Comment: Except under circumstance where you really, really know what you are doing, you assign a separate network to each VLAN. Routing is deterministic, and your PC will not try one interface then the other. What if it tries to send something to an address that is not in use at the time? Do you expect it to keep trying one interface after the other forever, looking for a response? It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Allright to set one thing staight. If nic1 is 192.168.2.8 vlan2 and nic2 is 192.168.2.9 vlan1 and i am on the pc and try to connect to 192.168.2.10 in vlan2. The pc will just try to connect to it over one of the nics and if it is unable to connect it will just fail?

Comment: Correct. The PC will use one interface for one network. It doesn't make a lot of sense to go through setting up separate VLANs without putting a different network on each. There is a reason that you want to separate the traffic, and you should do it completely. If you think you will get better performance for the PC, remember that the traffic for both VLANs is sharing the same uplink from the switch to the router anyway.

Comment: I know but like 800 mbps only goes trough the internal network. So i wanted to push this over one network adapter and use the other only for uplink to wan. On the zyxel roiter i can create vlans and link it to each lan port and then give each vlan its own dhcp server. On paper that shoukd be the case. I can create the vlan but csnnot link it to its own dhcp server.. Maybe need to change the router then...

Comment: Each network can have its own DHCP scope on a DHCP server, or you could simply statically configure the one network adapter.